# Teamcity display data about build in project overview

Tags: parameters, version, teamcity

I'm setting up our TeamCity 7 environment to allow managers to fetch artifacts, version data etc. easily from TeamCity.
However, upon downloading artifacts, I need them to be able to easily see the version and build number.

If you click to see the details for a build within TeamCity, you can see the build number under "Build Parameters". However, I need some way to display the version number from the project configuration file and display it somewhere in Teamcity, and I'd like to show it alongside the buildnumber and somewhere that's easier to find for non-technical users.

I do know how to get the version number from the config during the build, but can I save it and display it somewhere?

Comment: Can you just add build number to the build artifact name?

Comment: Hi Alexander. Thank you for your reply.
I don't consider the build numer as part of the filename as particularly user-friendly. As a matter of fact it already is part of the filename, but I'm still missing the version number.

I need both build number and version number to be visible in some structured list, existing or new.

Comment: I have the same concern and no solution yet. I guess it will take to write a TC plugin implementing the view you need. If you do, please make it available ;)

Comment: Hi Oliver. I figured out that you can take the VCS check-in number and use that as the build number, which is easy for users to find and see. It's set up on the first settings page for build targets.

About artifacts, it was all a matter of pointing TeamCity to the correct folder. Honestly it's a matter of trial and erorr, everything must be done differently between Xcode, Android and Windows projects.